# Linearization of a Matrix Inequality with Quadratic Terms

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-equations, control-theory, optimal-control

I derived the following matrix inequality for finding a stabilizing observer-based feedback gain $K$.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}-\lambda P& \tilde{A}^T & 0\\ \tilde{A} &-P^{-1} & \tilde{B}\\
0 & \tilde{B}^T & -(1-\lambda)I\end{bmatrix}\preceq0
$$
where $0<\lambda<1$ is a known parameter that I can set at will, $\tilde{B}$ is a known constant matrix, $P\succeq0$ is a semipositive definite matrix variable and
$$
\tilde{A}=\begin{bmatrix}A+BK & -BK\\
0 & A-LC\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $A$, $B$, $C$ and $L$ constant known matrices. The matrix $K$ is a variable.
It is known that if there exist such $P$ and $K$ satisfying this inequality, $A+BK$ is a stabilizing solution (all eigenvalues of $A+BK$ are inside the unit ball).

This problem is nonlinear, and I am having trouble to linearize it. The standard procedure would be a congruence transformation by multiplying both sides by $Q=P^{-1}$, resulting in

$$
\begin{bmatrix}-\lambda Q& Q\tilde{A}^T & 0\\ \tilde{A}Q &-P^{-1} & \tilde{B}\\
0 & \tilde{B}^T & -(1-\lambda)I\end{bmatrix}\preceq0
$$

But the product $\tilde{A}Q$ is still nonlinear. To make is simple, let

$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}Q_1 & 0\\
0 & Q_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Then, $\tilde{A}Q$ results in
$$
\tilde{A}=\begin{bmatrix}AQ_1+BKQ_1 & -BKQ_2\\
0 & AQ_2-LCQ_2\end{bmatrix}
$$
A solution would be calling $KQ_1$ say $W$ and $KQ_2$ say $V$, then the relation is linear. But there is another constraint between $W$ and $V$ which is nonlinear.

Does someone has an idea of how to linearize the problem?

Answer (score 4):

First, your original matrix inequality formulation is not the usual one I would have expected, and I'm not sure how you derived it.  However, a stabilizing, state-feedback based controller can be found by solving the (decoupled) LMIs:
$$
QA^T + AQ + BY + Y^TB^T < 0, \qquad A^TP + PA + WC + C^TW^T < 0,
$$
With $Q>0$ and $P>0$.  The controller is then $K=YQ^{-1}$ and the observer is $L=P^{-1}W$.  The proof that these decoupled LMIs indeed correspond to the *coupled* stability problem is not trivial.  It is given in Boyd's book, *Linear Matrix Inequalities in System and Control Theory* on page 111, and continued on page 117.  The book can be downloaded for free [here](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/lmibook/).

Comment: My matrix inequalities are derived for discrete-time systems, while the ones you presented are for continuous time system. The decoupled LMI's are correct but they do not solve my problem. The reason it that I have some additional matrix inequalities that depend on the matrix $P$. So, these inequalities you presented will end up being coupled with $P=Q^{-1}$.

Comment: You are correct, these are for a continuous-time system.  However, it is *not* true that $P=Q^{-1}$, i.e., these equations are not in fact coupled.  If the equations are satisfied, then there exists a $\lambda$ such that the function
$$V(x,\hat x) = \hat x^T P \hat x + (x-\hat x)^TQ^{-1}/\lambda (x-\hat x)$$
is a Lypunov function for the system (with observer).  Please look at the reference for the proof.